# Async Server Sockets are Acting Very Strangely

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I'm working on a simple debugging proxy server. Everything seems to be working fine, except 70% of requests get actually processed and in the rest I get strange data.

I have 3 functions:

```
    private static void Listen(Object obj)
    {
        log("**** Listen()");
        TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)obj;
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                while (!ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProxyServer2.ProcessClient), client)) ;
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException) { MessageBox.Show("ABORT EX"); }
        catch (SocketException) { MessageBox.Show("SOCKET EX"); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessClient(Object obj)
    {

        log("**** ProcessClient");
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;
        try
        {
            DoHttpProcessing(client);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void DoHttpProcessing(TcpClient client)
    {
        log("**** DoHttpProcessing");
        // handle all the http stuff
    }
```

This is where the weird part starts. When I make a request through the proxy, the request gets executed and returned, when I do it the second time, I get the last 10-30 bytes returned from the previous request.

**The strangest is that when I get these garbage bytes, DoHttpProcessing IS NOT being triggered (which doesn't make sense, since it contains the streams that send back response to the browser). Something is sending back the garbage data.. but what?**

It almost seems like the browser tries to fetch the new request using the same old connection? Can this be possible?

After DoHttpProcessing is triggered, all the streams are closed, so I don't understand how can server be using the old connection and get this garbage data!?!

Comment: Your server is not asynchronous. It's threaded. The problem is in the `DoHttpProcessing` code. You are aware that HTTP 1.1 can send multiple requests over the same socket?

Comment: And that a single HTTP 1.1 request may yield multiple response fragments?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know nether of these things. Does that mean threaded setup I have will not work with HTTP 1.1 I need to do a different approach?